# How do I execute a readStream of a tab-delimited file in Databricks?

Tags: dataframe, csv, pyspark, databricks

I have a 1000-line csv file containing tab-separated values, and want to read them into a data frame.

Here is my schema:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("TEST1", StringType(), True),
StructField("TEST2", StringType(), True),
StructField("TEST3", StringType(), True),
StructField("TEST4", StringType(), True),
StructField("TEST5", StringType(), True)])
```

Here is my readStream statement:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
.option("delimiter", "\t")
.option("path", "/mnt/data/data.tsv")
.schema(schema).load()
```

Running the readStream cell results in:

> df: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
> TEST1: string
> TEST2: string
> TEST3: string
> TEST4: string
> TEST5: string

In the next cell I executed

```
display(df)
```

and ended up with

> Query returned no results.

I think there is something wrong with my schema or readStream statements.  Is the tab delimiter set correctly?

Comment: `cloudFiles` source is used to automatically process new files in a given path. You could try `/mnt/data/` instead. If you only want that single file then no need for a readStream. Also some sample data from the .tsv might help.

Comment: Here is some of the tab-delimited data:

TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST5
1 Bob Smith Chantilly VA
2 Joe Schmo Vienna VA
3 Nicole Watson Lexington KY
4 Carol Brown Detroit MI
5 Kevin Lorton Dayton OH

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.  The path should not have been a specific file.  Rather, it should have been a file path containing wild cards.  After I changed the command to this:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
.option("delimiter", "\t")
.option("path", "/mnt/data/*.tsv")
.schema(schema).load()
```

it worked just fine.